# using ! on int in JAVA

Tags: java, int, not-operator, boolean-algebra

I was working on a program in java where I was creating a truth table of a full subtractor using a 2 dimensional array. While doing so, I wanted to compute the borrow out with the following formula:
   B(out) =    !(X).Y + (!(X ^ Y))B(in)

So, I wrote it like:

```
table[i][4] = ((!(table[i][2]))&table[i][1])+((!(table[i][2]^table[i][1]))*table[i][0]);

(here: table[i][4] = cell to store borrow out; 
       table[i][2] = cell storing X; 
       table[i][1] = cell storing Y; 
       table[i][0] = cell storing borrow in B(in) )
```

Whereas XOR(^) and AND(&) and or(|) worked fine, I got the following error for NOT(!):

```
operator ! cannot be applied to int
```

How can I correct this? Is there any other way to write this formula as a JAVA code? Please help.

Comment: Why are you using an `int` to store a `bool`ean value?

Comment: Is `X` suppose to be a function or a value?  If it's a function, then it would be required to return a `boolean` value, as `! 1` makes no sense, but `! true` does. `!` is used to invert `boolean` results

Comment: You need to use bitwise operators with `int`s,  not logical operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitwise complement operator that can be applied to integer values is the `~`, not `!`